# Old-Exam on Bellman Ford Algorithms, Need an indea?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, shortest-path, bellman-ford

We have a Directed Graph with 100 vertexes. v1 --> v2 --> ... v100 and all edges weights is equal to 1. we want to used bellman-ford for finding all shortest paths from v1 to other vertexes. this algorithm in each step check all edges in arbitrary order. if in each step the shortest distance v1 to all others vertexes is not changed, this algorithm halt. the number of steps is related to checking order of edges. what is the minimum and maximum of steps in this problem?

Solution: 2 and 100.

I think:

if we have this graph: v1->v2->v3->...->v100 we need 2. if we have V1->v2, V1->V3, V1->V4,... we need 100. and last if we have v99v100,v98v99,...,v3v2,v2v1 we need 100 again.

anyone can help or verify me?

Answer (score 0):

> v1->v2->v3->...->v100 we need 2

True, assuming you get the edges in that order (v1->v2, v2->v3, v3->v4...).

> V1->v2, V1->V3, V1->V4 ... we need 100.

False, Since all the distances are 1(there's a direct edge from the start node to all the others), then in one pass over the edges you are going to get the right results (regardless of the order of the edges), and the second pass to stop.

> v99v100,v98v99,...,v3v2,v2v1 we need 100.

True, assuming you have the same graph as in the first example, but the edges are in the opposite order.

Comment: my misunderstanding point is among graph and order of edge? is it possible to clear it for me in these three examples?

Comment: In the worst case you need one iteration to update one distance to the optimum, so max_distance + 1 iterations to get all the distances to the optimum. If the edges are in an order that allows you to use the optimum distance calculated then you potentially reduce the number of iteration (if this was along the longest path). To give an example if you have nodes v1, v2and v3 if you check v1->v2 before v2->v3 then you can update both v2 and v3 in the same iteration. If they are the other way around then you need 2 iterations.